# Define type of the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I play with a `Link` component from the `4.0.0-beta.2` - it has a field `component` - ability to override the root element.

I want to create a wrapper around `Link` - `MyLink` and pass a component through props:

```
interface Props {
  component: ???
}

const MyLink = ({component}: Props) => {
  <MUILink component={component} ... />
}
```

So from type definitions I didn't get how to construct the final type of the `component` prop:

```
declare const Link: OverridableComponent<{
  props: LinkBaseProps & {
    TypographyClasses?: TypographyProps['classes'];
    underline?: 'none' | 'hover' | 'always';
  };
  defaultComponent: 'a';
  classKey: LinkClassKey;
}>;
```

and OverridableComponent:

```
/**
 * a component whose root component can be controled via a `component` prop
 *
 * Adjusts valid props based on the type of `component`
 */
export interface OverridableComponent<M extends OverridableTypeMap> {
  <C extends React.ElementType>(props: { component: C } & OverrideProps<M, C>): JSX.Element;
  (props: DefaultComponentProps<M>): JSX.Element;
}
```

Can somebody help me to define the type of `component`?

Comment: `import { type ComponentType } from 'react';`

Comment: ah well...dunno if that works in ts but it's how you do it for flow

Comment: it can be a string "button", a component `React.Component<LinkProps>` or something else

Comment: Do you want to write your own overridable component or do you want to pass your `MyLink` into the Material-UI Link via `<MuiLink component={MyLink} />`?

Comment: @epsilon I want to create my own component - wrapper of `MuiLink` and use my new component instead of `MuiLink`, so usage will be  for example `<MyLink component='button' />`

Comment: @epsilon any idea?

Comment: @uladzimir We don't recommend you use this in your own components. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Material-UI. If so please include a full example that works at runtime and you which to type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like

```
interface Props {
  component: React.ElementType
}
```

does the trick for `Link` component.